# Rear lights not working on Chevrolet Matiz

Tags: electrical, lights

I noticed that the rear lights of my Matiz do not work (Or rather the guy behind me in a thunderstorm noticed...). The brake lights are fine, though. This is what I did:

1. checked the bulbs, they both look okay, but I changed them anyway, just in case.
2. checked the fuses and relays in the fuse box under the hood, they are all okay.
3. took a voltmeter to the sockets, and -- surprise -- read ~0V.
4. ripped apart most of the interior of the car to check the wiring, which is okay

I had no luck on finding a wiring diagram for the car.

I'm totally at a loss for what could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

After pulling *all* fuses in both fuse boxes, I found the "Interior lights" fuse in the fuse box under the dash was blown. After replacing it, the rear lights work again. What a misnomer.

Comment: The question is, why did it blow?  You may have a fault somewhere that will make it blow again, so you need to keep checking your lights are working.

Comment: I found that the interior light bulb (that lights up when you open the door) was blown, too. I suspect it took the fuse with it when it blew. But I'll keep checking.